# How to know postgres table column size

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a query which works on a loop and that queries 30K rows each time from DB. This works fine for certain type of data (let us call the group as company), so company A and B data are comparatively small in table but for company C the size is very huge.
for 30000 rows company A and B size is around 24 MB , but for company C it is 700 MB. Because of this scenario system started running out of memory for company C.

Now i have left with reducing fetch size from 30K to 5K so that company C also will be fetched without any issues.

I want this to happen dynamically because for company A and B if i reduce to 5K the DB traffic can increase drastically where it requires only for company C.

So i need to develop a code which can know company A,B,C's maximum column size (a BLOB) so based on the size i can decide 30K or 5K as the fetch size.

The whole code is in Java, Hibernate and Postgres

Comment: Are you claiming there's a significant performance difference when fetching 5K vs. 30K for your Company A?

Comment: There are two issues. 1 - when fetching 30k and 5k there are difference in total fetch time in seconds, here we are dealing with millions. So i do not want those seconds to get converted into minutes.

Comment: It's hard to say what would be the proper approach without seeing any code. You assume you've found the perfect solution, but to me it seems like a hack if anything. A few more round-trips to the database shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: I agree with Kayaman, anyway any data will be getting results in batches, even if ask it to get all the data. Second question, you may not want to materialize all the result in memory. You may prefer to load data using jdbc and handle records in a while loop, instead of collecting all the data in memory in a list and then handling it.

Comment: since each time total fetch row size can scale from 2 to 10 miillion so i have 30000 inside a while loop.

Comment: Shouldn't the blob be loaded lazily when it's needed instead? It's really hard to understand what your real problem is without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to know the size eg : pg_column_size,octet_length . But in my scenario they are inefficient because of the amount of time it take. So i changed my mind :).

Answer (score 0):

Example using PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT table_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)))
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY 2
```

Don't know if you can have a specific column size though